# Facing Issue while linking my debit card with GCP to activate free trial

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to link my HBL (Habib Bank Limited) and BOP (Bank of Punjab) account with GCP to activate free trial as I want to access multiple APIs regarding the Maps But I am unable to connect I have tried many times but every time I am getting a popup showing

**" Your card’s issuer declined this request. Contact your bank or use a different payment method. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-26]  "**

I have contacted banks' helplines they have enabled international transactions but I am still facing the same issue.
I am from Pakistan. Can anyone help me in this regard? Anyone from Pakistan?

Comment: SO is intended for programming questions. Billing or user support questions are off-topic. Please contact gcp billing support.

Comment: Try making a small prepayment. This should also activate your account: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment If the payment does not go thru contact your bank again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency
Check at the bottom the available payment options for Pakistan (link).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have checked the link for the countries not listed in the list at the link you shared. I have checked the payment methods finder (by clicking the link present at  https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/resources/currency ) and searched for Pakistan. It says the available payment methods for Pakistan are Debit/credit card. I am linking my debit card.

Answer (score 0):

for the GCP Free Tier account, I also had issues using my card initially. though am not from Pakistan, my case was I was using a verve debit card. I had to get another card from my bank, this time I got a VISA debit card. VISA card should work whether debit/credit card. my Master card gave me difficulty too hence I opted for a VISA debit card.